# Does Windows Task Scheduler work in modern standby? Can we register Windows Task Scheduler from UWP?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to register Windows Task Scheduler from UWP app programmatically? Does Windows Task Scheduler execute with defined trigger in modern standby?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I’m afraid you can’t do this in pure uwp application, because  there is no such API used to register a Task Scheduler work in UWP. If you do want to do this, you could try to do the job in a Win32 app. Then you could use [Desktop Bridge](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/desktop-bridge-8211-the-bridge-between-desktop-apps-and-the/ba-p/316488) to convert the Win32 app. Or make desktop extension for UWP project that packaged with Windows **Application Package Project**.

Comment: Whilst technically true, there are plenty of appropriate background triggers available to UWP apps to trigger background tasks in a fashion often similar to Task Scheduler.